# Property 'defaultColor' is missing in type 'NgxMatDatetimePicker<D>' but required in type 'CanColor'

Tags: angular, angular-material

While doing "ng build", I am facing the below errors.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker/lib/datetime-picker.component.d.ts:52:22 - error TS2420: Class 'NgxMatDatetimePicker' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.

and

> node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/color.d.ts:15:5
> 15     defaultColor: ThemePalette | undefined;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'defaultColor' is declared here.

Comment: did downgrading solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appear to multiple recent github issues referencing the same problem: [1](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/104), [2](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/108). One of the comments state that downgrading to version `@angular/material` to  version `10.1.3` seems to resolve the issue (see comment [here](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/108#issuecomment-688636328)) as a temporary workaround. In addition a fix seems to be in the works (see [here](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/pull/105)), but hasn't yet been merged as of writing this.

For now your best bet is to fix the `@angular/material` version to `10.1.3`

Comment: I'd updated my Angular to 13.1.1 and just fixed it by reinstalling @angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Answer (score 1):

I get the same errors after upgrading material to latest.  I am using a different datepicker (saturn-datepicker) but the same apart from that.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error by removing @angular/material 10.2.0  and install v 10.1.0

```
npm uninstal @angular/material
npm install @angular/material@10.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I face same error when upgrade project to angular version 12.
I solve it by update the "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker" to "5.1.1".